# batch processing with dependencies in python

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm looking for the best way to go about creating a job scheduler for different types of jobs. CJobs are threaded and some jobs need to finish before the next step in the process can run. This is currently all managed through a database table...which I think is fine. But if there's a better way to manage dependencies, I'm all ears.

Preferably I'd like to do this in python. I see there's parallel python module which looks great but am concerned about this dependency issue between jobs.

Can someone recommend anything that does what I need to do or how to go about doing this?

Much thanks!

D

UPDATE: This is to be done over a cluster of servers each with a limited set of available workers...1 per port. Does Celery or SCon support this?

Comment: So far I'm working with celery and rabbitMQ. Seems to do the trick so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a lot of success with [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/)

Comment: ok, I've looked into celery, I like it. My concern is if I have a group of jobs dependant on another group of jobs that I may have workers sitting waiting for batch 1 to finish before executing batch 2 rather than reallocate those workers to do other jobs in the queue...trying to avoid worker's stalling sitting idle. Maybe I need to ask a few more questions regarding scheduling and dependencies on the forum, if they have one.

Comment: Check out their mailing list or IRC channel on freenode (#celery)

Answer (score 3):

[Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) looks very interesting. It allows you to create workflows - sets of related jobs, which dependencies are managed by Luigi. It also has simple web interface providing dependency graph.

Answer (score 1):

[SCons](http://www.scons.org/) can be helpful for this.

It's biased toward software construction (compiling, linking, etc.) but you can easily define new result classes, new commands and new source classes so that it will process your data (and dependencies) properly.

Based on the update, you probably need something like [BuiltBot](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Buildbot), also.